# Tippy js, изменить контент если другой класс?

Tags: javascript

Привет использую плагин Tippy js

```
tippy('.product-item__compare', {
    content: 'Добавить в сравнение'
  });
```

Можно ли модифицировать что если у .product-item__compare есть класс active изменить контент

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Взял с оф документации. Как менять контент у каждого элемента. Создаёте `singleton` и передаёте на вход массив. Получаете все `item` через `classList` проверяете наличие того или иного класса и изменяете контент!

```js
import tippy, {createSingleton} from 'tippy.js';

const instances = [];
const items = document.querySelectorAll('.product-item__compare');

for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  const contentItem = items[i].classList.contains('active') ? 'Добавить в сравнение' : 'Другой контент'
  instances.push(
    tippy(items[i], {
      content: contentItem,
      updateDuration: 400,
    }),
  );
}

createSingleton(instances, {delay: [300, 600]});
```